# Execute javascript ads on a page loaded via AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

A image gallery with a jquery infinite scroll have some ads. This ads are loaded via javascript. When you scroll down the next page of images gets loaded.

**Example**

**1.** Image-Gallery.html (ads are displayed - everything OK)

**2.** scrolling down to the bottom

I can see in the console:

```
data-query: page40
data-start: 40
data-per-page: 20
Heading into ajax, "http://www.example.com/Image-Gallery/page40.html"
Using HTML via .load() method
```

**3.** Images and everything is showing but the ads are not displayed on page40.html.

**Example of adloading:**

In the head:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//adadapter.example.com/API-6/adscript.js"></script>
```

In the content:

```
<div id="mediacontent_rectangle">
<script type="text/javascript">mediacontent.includeAd("RECTANGLE");</script>
</div>

<div id="mediacontent_leaderboard">
<script type="text/javascript">mediacontent.includeAd("LEADERBOARD");</script>
</div>
```

Is there a way to execute all ads on page40.html and following when this page is called via ajax?

Thank you for a example. I tried many things like innerhtml and eval but I am pretty sure I did something wrong.